# Is the App Engine Launcher still part of the GCloud SDK's App Engine?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sdk

I followed the official guide on using the google cloud sdk with python 3, and I was able to install the latest sdk (`273.0.0`) with the google app engine and python components. Now I'd like to use the launcher instead of the cli commands in the guide to run my project but I cannot find it anywhere.

The README file in my current installation of the app engine in my `AppData/local` folder says that the `App Engine Launcher` should have a desktop shortcut and an executable at `C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\launcher\GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe` but neither shortcut nor executable path exist. I also looked through the `AppData` folder and didn't find it.

Was the launcher never present/removed from the app engine version I installed? Was it in the `README` by mistake? Or could the installation be incomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually didn't know that this tool existed, quite interesting.

Many people seemed to have liked this feature and used it extensively in order to have easier deployments and not have to go to the CLI but I think it might be deprecated.

I found relevant information in this [Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/5esgvujAqIQ) where people we're discussing the usability of this function and the transition of it when App Engine SDK joined the Cloud SDK.

You can see that [appcfg was deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appcfg-arguments) in July this year and the shutdown date is set for July 2020.

You might be able to still install it and use it with Python 2 until shutdown but I do not think there is a new version available for Python 3.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If this solved your question please mark it as accepted in order to provide more visibility to the answer. So yeah as I said in my answer, it will most likely not work with the newer versions now, as I haven't seen any information about a Python 3 version unfortunately. So you will have to use the gcloud SDK CLI to deploy instead of the interface you we're using with the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, many years ago, to deploy GAE, Google provided an installable desktop app called GoogleAeppEngineLauncher.  I'm quite certain that it is no longer available and would not even function if you were somehow able to obtain a copy.

You now must use the gcloud commands to deploy your app.